# Different gapps for every device?

Tags: applications, google-apps, customization

Hi everyone? I am thinking about changing my phone's rom and  I was wondering if every device need a special pack of Gapps (google apps) or if a pack works on different devices, what do you think?
Thanks for you answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GApps (Google Apps) are usually usable across devices and across Android versions but some Google apps feature different versions for different Android versions.

Those can include more functionality, better support for the latest version of Android and more.

If you need GApps, go to http://opengapps.org/ and select the version that applies to your phone and ROM (typically ARM64 and 6.0, 7.0 or 7.1) as well as the app bundle you want (with the AROMA package being completely modular and featuring nearly all apps).